# How do I disallow direct access to my db context and funnel all access through a single point?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, single-responsibility-principle

## Scenario

I have a `UserContext` class serving as the gateway to a database.

```
public class UserContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

I want to restrict direct access to the database (i.e. `UserContext.Users`), because I want to enforce audits. So far I had extra model classes that do the audit and implement interfaces that controllers use:

Controller -> Interface -> Model class -> DbContext

**But there is nothing to prevent the controllers (or rather other developers creating them) from accessing a DbContext directly.**

As far as I know I can't just allow access to some classes (models) and deny to others (controllers), so I need to protect `UserContext` from *all* classes.

## My Solution

The only solution I can think of is to make `Users` private and then implement access methods inside `UserContext`:

```
public class UserContext : DbContext
{
    private DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public changePassword(String username, String newPassword)
    {
        doAudit();
        Users.Single(user => user.Username == username).Password = newPassword;
        SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

But if I have to implement all db access methods inside `UserContext` it will become pretty big and have multiple responsibilities.

## Questions

1. Is there another way of preventing other classes from accessing db objects directly?
2. Is my proposed solution of putting all access methods into `UserContext` a violation of the Single Responsibility Principle? Or is this OK, because in this case it has only one responsibility: Allow access to the database?

Comment: Have you considered using the Repository pattern?

Comment: That seems like overkill to me. In order to have specific audit records (user x changed password of user y at time z) I need specific methods that only change the password and then can write this audit message. I don't want to allow all CRUD operations because then I would have to audit all of them in a meaningful way.

Comment: @problemofficer, 1.) Is there another way? A: Yes. 2.) SRP Violation? A: Yes. Suggestion: Expose service that provides only the necessary functionality and applies you business rules which is what audit is.

Comment: @Nkosi: But how do I allow this service to access the db context but nobody else?

Answer (score 1):

### Securing your code by nesting it.

You could create a class and secure your context by nesting the various classes inside of it, but it's a bit of an unusual pattern.

```
// sealed public class
public sealed class SecuredUserService : ISecuredUserService
{
    private readonly UserContext _context;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public SecuredUserService(ILogger logger)
    {
        if (logger == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));

        _logger = logger;
        _context = new UserContext()
    }

    // expose a secure interface / method
    public bool TryChangePassword(IUser user, string value)
    {
        _logger.Log("password was NOT changed.");
        return false;
    }

    // secure the context
    private class UserContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    }

    // secure the model
    private class User : IUser
    {
        public int ReadOnlyInteger { get; set; }
        public bool WriteOnlyBool { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReadWriteDateTime { get; set; }
        public string SecretString { get; set; }
    }
}
```

These would be the public interfaces for the above.

```
// public exposed interfaces
public interface IUser
{
    int ReadOnlyInteger { get; }
    bool WriteOnlyBool { set; }
    DateTime ReadWriteDateTime { get; set; }
}

// public exposed interface
public interface ISecuredUserService
{
    bool TryChangePassword(IUser user, string value);
}
```

*Note: To take it even further, you can put the class into a separate namespace.*

Comment: I want to implement an audit log that e.g. creates a record whenever a user changes his password. Because I can't trust controllers to always ensure the creation of the audit record, I want to force them to use a predefined interface e.g. IChangePassword that is implemented by ChangePassword which accesses the db (and changes the password) and also makes sure that an audit record is created. At the same time there must be no other way for controllers to access the db, they MUST go through ChangePassword, because then I can make sure that audit records are created.

Comment: @problemofficer - Ok. So basically a service layer w/ auditing? If you were very serious about the security aspect, you could even push it out to its own namespace too.

Comment: @problemofficer - would it still be suitable if you had an attribute flag that allowed certain models/controllers specific access, or does it need to be totally isolated?

Comment: I would prefer for it do be totally isolated. Basically I am afraid that other developers will not bother using `ChangePassword` but access the db directly.

Comment: I have more questions :) : 1.) What practical advantages are there for making the `User` class private and putting it inside `SecuredUserService`? I would leave it outside just to make the enclosing class smaller. I don't mind if others know its structure. They could reuse this class for form validation for example. 2.) I am fairly new to C#. How would creating separate namespaces aid the separation. Can't developers simply `using` the other namespace and access the other class nonetheless?

Comment: @problemofficer - **(1)** It's very important to remember that classes are passed by reference, which means that if you don't want them to be able to change the property of something you specifically want to reserve for on the `SecuredUserService` then it is guaranteed when you nest it inside the way it is done in the example.

Comment: **(2)** Yes and No, Namespaces are a way of managing class hierarchy and structure. A `public` class there is really no different than a `public` class in the same namespace. However, if you have a separate namespace the `internal` access-modifier becomes effective.

Comment: @problemofficer - Please create new questions, comments are not appropriate for detailed Q&A.

Comment: I was hoping you would incorporate your comments answers into your main answer. :) Other people might ask themselves the same questions, so it be useful for future readers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151154/discussion-between-problemofficer-and-svek).

Answer (score 0):

Create a [repository](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) that will expose only the functionality you deem acceptable. This way you'll have a centralized, testable gateway to your database.

Answer (score 0):

While deviating from the current solution as least as possible, consider splitting responsibilities that would otherwise be in `UserContext` into other classes `UserContext` will control and delegate to. For example, a `PasswordChange` class is responsible for auditing and carrying out password changes. `UserContext` can then delegate password changing to the `PasswordChange` class:

```
public class PasswordChange
{
    private DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public PasswordChange(DbSet<User> users)
    {
        Users = users;
    }

    public void Execute(String username, String newPassword)
    {
        doAudit();
        Users.Single(user => user.Username == username).Password = newPassword;
    }
}

public class UserContext : DbContext
{
    private DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public changePassword(String username, String newPassword)
    {
        new PasswordChange(Users).Execute(username, newPassword);
        SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

A cleaner, but more involved solution would be to define an `IUserRepository` interface with a `ChangePassword` method or a more fine-grained `IPasswordChange` interface with an `Execute` method if size is a concern. Concrete implementations of these interfaces would use `UserContext` to carry out database related tasks while also doing auditing. In case of going with `IUserRepository`:

```
public interface IUserRepository
{
    public void ChangePassword(string username, string newPassword);
    //other user related methods
}

public class SqlUserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    UserContext UserContext { get; }

    public SqlUserRepository(UserContext userContext)
    {
        UserContext = userContext;
    }

    public void ChangePassword(string username, string newPassword)
    {
        DoAudit();
        UserContext.Users.Single(user => user.Username == username).Password = newPassword;
        UserContext.SaveChanges();
    }
    //other user related methods
}
```

In case of going with `IPasswordChange`:

```
public interface IPasswordChange
{
    public void Execute(string username, string newPassword);
}

public class SqlPasswordChange : IPasswordChange
{
    UserContext UserContext { get; }

    public SqlPasswordChange(UserContext userContext)
    {
        UserContext = userContext;
    }

    public void Execute(string username, string newPassword)
    {
        DoAudit();
        UserContext.Users.Single(user => user.Username == username).Password = newPassword;
        UserContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Controllers would then accept `IUserRepository` or `IPasswordChange` interfaces through their constructors. Through these interfaces they would access concrete implementations, which ensures that auditing will always take place and that controllers cannot access the database directly.

To prevent controllers from constructing `UserContext` or having any references to it at all, `UserContext` and related database classes like `SqlUserRepository` or `SqlPasswordChange` can be moved to a separate assembly. Then the classes or just their constructors can be marked as internal to prevent accessing them from the controller.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer. What I don't understand though is: Doesn't the `UserContext` class still need a public constructor? What would the controllers prevent form just using it directly?

Comment: `UserContext` and other database related classes like `SqlUserRepository` or `SqlPasswordChange` can be moved into a separate assembly. Then either the classes or their constructors can be marked internal. This way controllers won't have access to their constructors or any access at all, since the controllers will be referencing interfaces anyway. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Houndolon - if you read through the comments of my answer, he wants to have the **UserContext totally isolated**. Your solution isn't isolating the UserContext class itself, which means you could still do `new UserContext` somewhere else in the code. -- I think that's what is being said since the first comment.

Comment: @Svek I've updated the answer. The `UserContext` can be isolated by moving it into another assembly and marking it or its constructor internal.

Comment: Your entire answer could just be your last comment. A lot of solutions that are placed in a different namespace would achieve the same result. Which I think is probably a solid answer in the first place.